# woocommerce set user meta value as default field value if exist

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to set the default field value of a custom confirm email field in checkout.

If billing_email exists in user meta I would like to set the meta value as default value for the field.

If billing_email not exists in user meta I want to set the meta value of user_email as default value for the field.

I tried this:

```
$fields['billing_email_confirm'] = array(
'label' => 'confirm email *',
'class' => array( 'form-row-last' ),
'priority' => 9999,
);

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$havemeta = get_user_meta($customer_id, 'billing_email', false);

if ($havemeta)
{
$fields['billing_email_confirm']['default'] = $current_user->user_email;
} else {
$fields['billing_email_confirm']['default'] = $current_user->billing_email;
}

return $fields;
}
```

It works if the billing_email exists in user meta. But if not the field is empty.

Answer (score 0):

There are few logical mistakes in your code, here is cleaned code with explanations:

```php
$fields['billing_email_confirm'] = array(
    'label'    => 'confirm email *',
    'class'    => array( 'form-row-last' ),
    'priority' => 9999,
);

// Check is customer ID is available or not?
if ( ! empty( $customer_id ) ) {
    // Get customer data using customer id.
    $customer = get_userdata( $customer_id );

    // Get billing email from user meta.
    // 3rd param should be true as we need single value not an array.
    $billing_email = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_email', true );

    // Check if billing email is empty or not?
    if ( ! empty( $billing_email ) ) {
        // when billing email is not empty.
        $fields['billing_email_confirm']['default'] = $billing_email;
    } else {
        // When billing email is empty use, user account email.
        $fields['billing_email_confirm']['default'] = $customer->user_email;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond. But it don't works :(